# Recommended version of operating system and recommended version of SQL-server database for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am going to install a new SharePoint server 2013, and currently I am not sure of which operating system and database to go with either:-

For the operating system either to :-

1. The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Standard, Enterprise,
2. OR The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter

For the database either:-

1. The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
2. OR The 64-bit edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1.

So I have the following two questions:-

1. Is it recommended to go with windows server 2012 & SQL server 2012?.
2. Or it I more stable and more reliable to go with windows server 2008 & database server 2008.?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint 2013, the combination of Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012 is recommended approach but the 2008 R2 & SQL Server 2008 R2 (with all the latest SP & Hotfixes for both) is still a very solid option (and quite lightweight memory wise)

I find it hard to ask my customers to upgrade their server OS and SQL system just to use SharePoint 2013 and I have two production farms in 2008R2+SQL Server 2008R2 SP2 that are running smoothly.

If it's a brand new environment and you don't have licences constraint, go for 2012 editions, otherwise, 2008 OS/ SQL (R2 SP1) are already and will keep on being supported

Hope it helps.